# json.loads in python containing non standard characters

Tags: javascript, python, json, unicode

What I'm trying to do is grab some text in my web application (string literals containing non English characters such as ă) with Javascript. Pass it to an object and then use JSON.Stringify() on the object, and then pass that to a python script.

The Python script is intended to load the json data and eventually print the text on a POS printer so the final data has to be in ascii hex format of a specific code page which means ill have to perform some character conversion either before or after the python script gets the data.

Basically something like this:

```
someObject.arrayOfTextInputs.push("how can I handle the ă character");
--run a python script and pass to it: JSON.Stringify(someObject) --
```

In Python:

```
jsonStuff = sys.argv[1]
myObject= json.loads(jsonStuff)
```

Now if I simply pass the strings as is, the python script hangs upon json.loads because of the ă character. If i replace the character prior to Stringify, with an'\xNN' representation matching a value from a Code Page i need, the json.loads still hangs.
Same thing for using '\uNNNN'.

I also printed out the json i get before handing it over to json.loads() and normally it just prints out some weird hex? character/image instead of ă.
However, replacing it to its utf-8 repesentation (in javascript) \xc4\x83, makes the print in python display the character properly (altho it creates problems in the next steps).
Same thing happens with replacing ă with \xC7 which is the matching character in code page 852 (latin-2) and then jsonStuff.decode('cp852')

What are my options here?

***Edit: Thanks for the welcome!***
I am using Python 2.7 which from what I've gathered uses standard ascii encoding.

- If i skip any conversion i get the exception: ValueError: Invalid control character at some character/byte..
- If I convert the character in Javascript (before doing Stringify() on the object) with an escape matching the same character from an utf-8 table: "\u0103" i get the same exception.
- If I convert the character to some utf-8 character that falls into the standard ascii character set ("\u0045"), it loads fine. I guess the decoder can automatically map the unicode "regular" characters into their ascii representatives.
  Same thing for converting to say "\x45".
- If I add strict=False argument to the loads() function, i can load any escaped character but then I'm not sure how to handle it in my python script.

I have to admit, the stringify and loads() part really makes me lose track, since I'm starting out with utf8 in my IDE, using escape characters from a different encoding, then calling stringify (only utf8 encoded stuff is valid json?) and pass it into python which cant handle utf8 past the standard character set. And I have to end up with '\xNN' of a specific code page(say Latin-2) in the end just before the print.

Should I try to pass anything using strict=False and handle it from there within python, or is it possible to send everything encoded using some code page?
I'll add some code in a bit.

Comment: `json.loads()` won't *hang* even if you give him invalid input. It will raise an exception. If it does raise an exception then [edit] your question and include the traceback. Check what happens if you pass `"\u0103"`.